# Third-order homogeneous linear recurrence relation with quadratic coefficients

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I am looking for techniques to simplify or solve the recurrence
$$
\sum_{k=0}^3(a_k n^2 + b_k n + c_k) x_{n+k} = 0
$$
with initial conditions $x_0,x_1,x_2$. The coefficients $a_k,b_k,c_k$ are unrelated in general. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have generating functions for the $a_k$, $b_k$, and $c_k$?

Comment: I know $a_k,b_k,c_k$; they are constants for the purposes of this problem. Not sure what you mean by generating functions for them.

Comment: I misread the problem

Comment: This is a special case of [Holonomic sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_function).

Answer (score -1):

by evaluating at $n=0$ you obtain:
$$x_3=-\frac{c_0x_0+c_1x_1+c_2x_2}{c_3}$$
at $n=1$:
$$x_4=-\frac{(a_0+b_0+c_0)x_1+(a_1+b_1+c_1)x_2+(a_2+b_2+c_2)x_3}{(a_3+b_3+c_3)}\\=-\frac{1}{a_3+b_3+c_3}\sum_{k=0}^2(a_k+b_k+c_k)x_{k+1}$$
at $n=2$:
$$x_5=-\frac{(4a_0+2b_0+c_0)x_2+(4a_1+2b_1+c_1)x_3+(4a_2+2b_2+c_2)x_4}{(4a_3+2b_3+c_3)}$$

and in general we can say:
$$x_k=-\frac{1}{\left[(k-3)^2a_3+(k-3)b_3+c_3\right]}\sum_{j=0}^2\left[(k-3)^2a_j+(k-3)b_j+c_j\right]x_{k+j-3}\qquad\forall k\ge4$$